# Regex: Odd number of occurrences of a char

Tags: regex

Found nothing specific to my problem in searches:

I have an Alphabet {a,b,c}, where I need to produce a set of strings that have an odd number of a's.

**Valid**:   ababaccccc   baaaccccc cab  caabaaac

**InValid**: baac  caacccb  caabbbaac

Attempt:

`\b[bc]*a{3}[bc]*\b` but this is very limited.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following regex [should work](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Cb%5Bbc%5D%2aa%28%28%5Bbc%5D%2aa%29%7B2%7D%29%2a%5Bbc%5D%2a%5Cb&input=ababaccccc%20baaaccccc%20cab%20caabaaac%0Abaac%20caacccb%20caabbbaac%0Aa%0Aaa%0Aaaa%0Aaaaa%0Abca%0Acaca%0Acacaca).

```
\b[bc]*a(([bc]*a){2})*[bc]*\b
```

Comment: @Imray \b means word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

If you need solution without regex i.e. Java:

```
String arr[] = {"ababaccccc",  "baaaccccc" , "caabaaac", "baac", "caacccb", "caabbbaac"};   

for (String string : arr) {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
                if (string.charAt(i) == 'a') {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            if ((counter & 1) == 0) {
                System.out.println(string + " is invalid");
            } else {
                System.out.println(string + " is valid");
            }
        }
```

Comment: why not have a boolean variable called valid, which starts as false and changes state whenever we encounter the character 'a':

String arr[] = {"ababaccccc",  "baaaccccc" , "caabaaac", "baac", "caacccb", "caabbbaac"};

for (String string : arr) {

  bool valid = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
       if (string.charAt(i) == 'a') {
          valid = !valid;
          counter++;
        }
     }

     if (valid) {
       System.out.println(string + " is valid");
     } else {
       System.out.println(string + " is invalid");
     }
}

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to

1. split the input string on whitespace
2. count the 'a's in every element
3. based on the outcome of count accept or reject ?

Answer (score 0):

An example for python regex:
This returns match if there is an odd number of m in sequence

```
'(m|(m(m{2})+))$'
```

And this returns the match if there is an odd number of m in sequence or with h's between the m's

```
'(h*mh*|(h*mh*(h*mh*m)+)h*)$'
```

Now you can make other combinations from this idea :)