# Regular Expression Clarity

Tags: regex, binary, regular-language

I have a question

> Write down a regular expression for all binary strings that end with
>   an even (nonzero) number of 0's.

So far I have come up with `L = { (0/1)* (00)+ }`

But it doesn't seem to work all the time. The (0/1)* can generate 0110 and the (00)+ will add 0110 00 - which doesn't make an ending of even number of 0's.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using + to denote a superscript + for 1 or many, and a forward slash to denote a normal plus for a union.

This would work:

```
L = { (0/1)* 1/E (00)+ }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution.

Its `L = { (0/1)* 1/E (00)+ }`

Comment: is this regex? `0/1`  `1/E`?

Comment: According to my lecturer, he suggests to use a slash for OR instead of + to avoid ambiguity when using + for 1 or more

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
\b(([01]*1(0{2})+)|((00)+))\b
```

You can test it [here](http://regexpal.com/)

You can also check this similar problem:

[Regex: Odd number of occurrences of a char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297907/regex-odd-number-of-occurences-of-a-char)

Answer (score 0):

Per condition you stated in your problem. Shouldn't it be { (0/1)* 1(00)+ } ?
* denotes 0 or more occurrences. Whereas + denotes one or more occurrences.